# Create a local database in windows phone 8.1

Tags: .net, database, sqlite, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I have to create a local database for my application. Can someone help me?
I want write it in sql with a query like "create table ..." not with sqlite-net.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use SQLite without SQLite-net.

Just get it from the [Gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b) and do stuff like:

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);

command.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS beispiel ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO beispiel (id, name) VALUES(NULL, 'Test-Datensatz!')";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

command.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM beispiel ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 1";

SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
  Console.WriteLine("Name: \"{p}\"", reader[0].ToString());
}

reader.Close();
reader.Dispose();

command.Dispose();
```

Comment: can you give me some hints for create the database?
Where I can create it? How?

Comment: Added a sample to the answer.

Comment: I have some problem with
connection
SqLiteDateRader
ExecuteReader
Console
Dispose

I dont found it

Comment: The Sample is quite old, maybe you should look up the latest documentation (you will also find some more current samples there).